# Sorting Pictures by name-column "record date" with nautilus

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, date, photo, sort

i use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS a few days now and i like to shot photos :-). So far, i load all my pictures on my ubuntu system (approximatly 15000). But when i want to sort them in their folders by the record-date i dont find an option to do this. I came from windows and in the explorer it wasn a big thing.

So my question is, if anyone out there know an extension for nautilus or a easy way to sort my pictures to view. I tried "Shotwell" but it takes very long time to import 15000 photos, so i aborted the import process.

Maybe you can help me. This would be great.

Thank you...

Comment: When you right click in the Pictures folder don't you see Arrange Items--> By Modification Date ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not found a way in nautilus but i found a program called "gThumb" it is a very fast and usefull picture viewer.
With this tool you can view the pictures as a kind of explorer and so you don't have to import something.
To sort pictures you can go to "View" -> "Sort by" -> "sort by record-date" (I just translated in english from my language so there are maybe different words in original)

Hope I could anyone help with this.